# mitmproxy not displaying ARP-poisoned traffic

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

I have a target computer at `10.0.0.14` and gateway at `10.0.0.1`. I successfully insert myself as a MITM by running

```
sudo arpspoof -i wlp3s0 -t 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.14
sudo arpspoof -i wlp3s0 -t 10.0.0.14 10.0.0.1
```

And when I run `arp` on the target machine, I see that `10.0.0.1` is associated with my MAC. On my machine, I then run

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlp3s0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Finally, I run `ping google.com` on the target machine. When I run `sudo tcpdump | grep 10.0.0.14` on my machine, I see lots of packets involving the ping requests. But when I run `mitmproxy -T --host` I don't get anything! What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Here's the result of `ifconfig`:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:49445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4511425 (4.5 MB)  TX bytes:4511425 (4.5 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          inet addr:10.0.0.6  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:280:4900:e583:a64e:31ff:fe63:ccdc/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a64e:31ff:fe63:ccdc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:502914 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:306905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:489697020 (489.6 MB)  TX bytes:70008617 (70.0 MB)
```

Comment: Are you referring to the ping request? You won't see those in mitmproxy, only HTTP.

Comment: @MaximilianHils Wow XD I didn't know ping uses a different protocol... (noob here sorry) ya I tried some HTTP traffic and it worked beautifully! Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mitmproxy will not display `ping`s, it will only display HTTP (or, with some tweaks, TCP) traffic.